# Retiring the once only volume, holding important looking files

Tags: synology

`/volume1` was once my only volume, and it's has been joined by `/volume2` in preparation for retiring `/volume1`.

Having relocated all my content I can see lots of files I cannot explain. Unusually they are all prefixed with `@`, e.g.

```
/volume1$ ls -als
total 430144
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root        344 May  2 16:19 .
     4 drwxr-xr-x  24 root    root       4096 May  2 16:18 ..
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root        156 Jun 29 15:57 @appstore
     0 drwx------   1 root    root          0 Apr 11 04:03 @autoupdate
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root         14 May  2 16:19 @clamav
   332 -rw-------   1 root    root     339245 Jan 23 13:50 @cnid_dbd.core.gz
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 admin   users        76 Aug 19  2020 @database
     0 drwx--x--x   1 root    root        174 Jun 29 15:57 @docker
     0 drwxrwxrwx+  1 root    root         24 Jan 23 15:27 @eaDir
420400 -rw-------   1 root    root  430485906 Jan  4 05:06 @G1.core.gz
     0 drwxrwxrwx   1 root    root         12 Jan 21 13:47 @img_bkp_cache
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root         14 Dec 29 18:45 @maillog
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root         60 Dec 29 18:39 @MailScanner
     0 drwxrwxr-x   1 root    root        106 Oct  7  2018 @optware
  7336 -rw-------   1 root    root    7510134 Jan 24 01:33 @Plex.core.gz
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 postfix root        166 Oct 12  2020 @postfix
  2072 -rw-------   1 root    root    2118881 Jan 17 03:47 @rsync.core.gz
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root         88 May  2 16:19 @S2S
     0 drwxr-xr-x   1 root    root          0 Jan 23 13:50 @sharesnap
     0 drwxrwxrwt   1 root    root         48 Jun 29 15:57 @tmp
```

I have two questions

1. what does the `@` prefix signify, and
2. how can I move/remove them, given that *something's* going to miss these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experimentation it seems the answers are:

1. Nothing - they're a convention used by the Synology packaging system, it appears.
2. With one exception I didn't need to consider the consequences of removing the file system on which these stood. The `@appstore` directory clearly holds the installed Synology packages, and after pulling `/volume1` they showed in the Package Center as "needing repair". Once they were repaired, the same `@` prefixed directories appeared in the new volume - *and* the configuration was retained - so it appears these directories hold only the immutable software components.

**The exception**: I use `ipkg` mostly for `fetchmail`. I took a listing of the installed packages as well as the `fetchmailrc`, and then reinstalled the same packages once "Easy Bootstrap Installer" was ready for use (repair didn't work on this, but uninstall and reinstall worked fine).